# Cardinality of order-preserveing function set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Cardinality of order-preserveing function set:

$1. A:=\left\{0,1 \right\}^\mathbb N,(0<1)$ regular order on $\mathbb N.$

$2. B:=\mathbb N ^ \left\{0,1 \right\},(0<1), $regular order on $\mathbb N.$

$3. C:=\mathbb N^\mathbb R$,regular order.

$4. D:=\mathbb R^\mathbb N$,regular order.

**My solution:**

$1.$ Define $y\in \mathbb N$ as the first number that exist $f(y)=1$.

Then $\forall x\in \mathbb N$ that $x<y$ exist $f(x)<f(y) \implies f(x)=0.$

There are $\aleph_0$ for y $\implies |A|=\aleph_0.$

$2.\exists y\in \mathbb N $ exists $ f(1)=y $.

Then $f(0)=x \iff x<y.$

There are $\aleph_{0}$ options of $y$ and fintie options of $x(n \in \mathbb N)$ then $|B|=\aleph_0 \cdot |n| = \aleph_0.$

$3.$ I have no idea how to deal with this problem, I dont know how to find the increaseing function of $C$

$4.$ I know there are $\mathfrak c$ increase function from $\mathbb N to \mathbb N$ so this is the lower bound.

The higher bound is $|\mathbb R ^{ \mathbb N}|=|\mathbb R| ^ {|\mathbb N|} = \mathfrak c.$

Then $|D|=\mathfrak c$.

I'd be grateful for your help and feedback!

Comment: @SaucyO'Path $\forall x,y \in \mathbb R \ $exist $x<y \space \implies  \space f(x)<f(y)$

Comment: When i think about it , the answer is $|C|=0$ since $|R|=\mathfrak c , |N|=\aleph_0$ then there is no preserved-order  function between them.